# Unable to Achieve Text Decoration in React Component

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently working on a ToDoItem component in React, and I'm facing an issue with achieving the intended styling. The goal is to apply the "line-through" text decoration when the list item is clicked, but the styling is not being applied as expected.

Here's the code for my ToDoItem component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function ToDoItem(props) {
  const [completed, setCompleted] = useState(false);

  const textD = () => {
    setCompleted((prevValue) => {
      console.log(prevValue);
      return !prevValue;
    });
  };

  return (
    <li
      onClick={textD}
      style={{ textDecoration: completed ? "line-through" : "none" }}
    >
      {props.listItem}
    </li>
  );
}

export default ToDoItem;
```

The console.log statements in the component are not printing any messages, which makes debugging challenging. I would like to achieve the "line-through" text decoration when the list item is clicked, but it's not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

the code seems right but the Console.log is inside the `textD`,move console.log  outside the `textD`

here's what i came up with

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

function ToDoItem(props) {
  const [completed, setCompleted] = useState(false);

  const textD = () => {
    setCompleted((prevValue) => !prevValue);
  };

  console.log("Completed:", completed);

  return (
    <li
      onClick={textD}
      style={{ textDecoration: completed ? "line-through" : "none" }}
    >
      {props.listItem}
    </li>
  );
}

export default ToDoItem;
```